# Get rid of IAR compile warning Pa039 ? "use of address of unaligned structure member"

Tags: c, pointers, compiler-errors, iar

IAR compiler for ARM...

I have a structure packed using

```
 #pragma pack(push, 4)
 typedef struct {
    int a;
    double b;
 } my_t;
 #pragma pack(pop)
```

I want to take the address of a field and then cast to a `char *`.

```
my_t d;
char * p = (char *)(&(d.b));
```

Can I achieve this warning free without disabling the warning using a pragma?

Comment: This seems like a false alarm to me. Compiler doesn't seem to be sophisticated enough to see that this special case is fine. I would suggest that you just disable the warning, and restore it after you are done.

Comment: @user694733 Yes I want to do this in a tidy portable way.

Comment: Well, the protability is kind of out already with the `pack`. If you want serialization portably, then it's better to avoid structs altogether. Convert each member manually to byte array or back using bitshifts. That will also sort out the endianness issues.

Answer (score 5):

Personally I would switch off the warning for this section of code using pragmas like in the example below.

```
char *g(void)
{
#pragma diag_suppress=Pa039
  return (char *)(&d.b);
#pragma diag_default=Pa039
}
```

If this is not an option, it is possible to find the offset of `b` in `my_t` and add this to the address of `d`

```
char *f(void)
{
  return (char *)&d + offsetof(my_t, b);
}
```

Comment: I think offsetof is an actual macro. If so then it will generate the warning too. I started down that rabbit hole but I needed typeof() and portability became an issue.

Comment: Unfortunately I need it to be portable too so I would want to wrap the pragmas and I end up with six in total.

Comment: @WilliamJBagshaw Since offsetof is intended for precisely this kind of things it uses internal tricks in the compiler to avoid the warning. Both of my examples gives a clean compile in iccarm 8.30.

Comment: @WilliamJBagshaw The offsetof version also compiles clean in gcc (Arm Embedded Processors 7-2017-q4-major) and armclang (ARM Compiler 6.7).

Answer (score 1):

Because a `double` is typically larger than an `int`, and because the struct is packed, the field `b` is not properly aligned when the smaller field appears first.

Put the larger field first and both should be properly aligned:

```
 typedef struct {
    double b;
    int a;
 } my_t;
```

Comment: Unfortunately swapping members won't work. `double` will still be out of it's normal alignment due to `pack`. Compiler seems to take into account that `my_t` might be used in array, even if it's not really the case here.

Comment: The main reason for using a packed structure is as a "template" to interpret data from another source. For example a communication protocol. So swapping around the order is not always an option.

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly**: you should be sure that double variable aligned inside data type by 4 bytes, your code is correct!

```
 #pragma pack(push, 4)
 typedef struct {
    int a;
    double b;
 } my_t;
 #pragma pack(pop)
```

**Secondly**: your variable address should be located corresponded

```
#pragma data_alignment = 4 
my_t d;
char * p = (char *)(&(d.b));
```

Comment: This is trivial. If the field is suitably aligned for a double there will be no warning. The question is about how to avoid the warning when the field for some reason is not suitably aligned.

Comment: is not trivial, is a typical mistake. Many people think that data packing and data alignment the same stuff. Keywords are ` #pragma data_alignment = 4`  You can have packed structure but this structure can be located on 0x20000001 address. For example, the compiler can use VLDR instruction to load value from structure field but this instruction must have address values are multiples of 4!
So, using #pragma data_alignment = 4 will guarantee correctly located and the warning is disappeared